# Delayed jobs die silently only on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

So on my machine, the daemonized version of delayed_jobs runs like a charm.

On my server (Same ruby version, same file architecture, same gems), it fails.

Launching `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run` works on the server

However, `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` does nothing, no file created in tmp/pids, nothing in the log.

How can I troubleshoot this issue ?

Comment: Any chances of having more details such as your Ruby version, the OS and its version as well as the file arch and also delayed_job version...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue

In my production log, I had this message :

> Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection:

Adding `reconnect: true` in my database.yml fixed the issue.

Not sure why it was working on my local machine though, probably not the same mysql settings between my OSX MySQL and my Debian MySQL